# setOnItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

Am trying to get my setOnItemClickListener working, but when I add the method, Eclipse says that I should remove the "@Override" annotation, if I do, the listener don't work. The thing is that I need to capture the "click" event and do something...
Here is my method:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override //<-- this is the annotation that eclipse says I should remove
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


    }
});
```

Am really sure that the problem is not the method itself, i suppose that it's something else.
Please take a look to my Activity and tell me what am doing wrong:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class Sounds extends Activity{

ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.list_table);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        DB_Helper myDbHelper = new DB_Helper(this);       
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        } 

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            String[] columns = new String[3];
            columns[0] = "id_Category";
            columns[1] = "category_name";
            columns[2] = "image_name";   
            songsList = myDbHelper.selectAll("Categories",columns);
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }

    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click event for single list row
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

          //ToDo something...
        }
    }); 
 }




 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about_sounds, menu);

        return true;
    }
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch(item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.about_sounds_item1:
         Intent talesToLearnActivity = new Intent(Sounds.this, AboutSounds.class);
            startActivity(talesToLearnActivity);
         break;
     default:

         break;
     }

     return true;
 }
}
```

If I remove the annotation, my method dont capture the event. If I do not remove it, my app dont compile.
BTW Am working with Android 2.2 SDK

Comment: Is this inside your `onCreate()`?

Comment: @codeMagic it looks like it is.

Comment: Yes, it is inside the onCreate()

Comment: Sorry, either was edited or I didn't see that

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, what do you have compiler level set at? "Project -> Propertied->Java Compiler"

Comment: @codeMagic I also was thinking about that one. But, as you see in his code, he is using already the `@Override` annotation in other methods.

Comment: @Cristian you're just going to get me at every turn, aren't you? :P

Comment: @codeMagic no, I think I was just as curious and intrigued as you were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check project properties and make sure that `Java Compiler -> JDK Compliance -> Complier Compliance Level` is 1.6.

Comment: Why wouldn't it complain about the other `@Override` usage?

Comment: `@Overidde` was first introduced in JDK 1.5, but it was expanded to method implementation in Java 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

check properties in your project and make sure that Java Compiler -> JDK Compliance -> Complier Compliance Level is 1.6. otherwise it will not been work.